# GRIDVIEW changing cell or row fonts dynamically

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, webforms

Using a "GRIDVIEW"

I have the gridview  (not a datagridview)  populated via a dataset containing 91 different font names.

The Gridview has two columns.
Col 0 has the text "TEST TEXT" in it in all 91 rows.
Col 1 has the names of the fonts.
When the gridview loads I want the "TEST TEXT" in col 0 to display using the font in col1
I've verified that the dataset has the correct fonts in it by stepping through the code and can see the names in col2

I'm not having any success getting the fonts to change using this code.

```
 For Each ros As GridViewRow In GVfonts.Rows
 fontnameis = Replace(GVfonts.Rows(I).Cells(1).Text, ".otf", "")
 GVfonts.RowStyle.Font.Name = (fontnameis)
 GVfonts.Rows(I).Cells(0).Text = "Sample Text"
 GVfonts.Rows(I).Cells(0).Width = 150
 GVfonts.Rows(I).Height = 40
 GVfonts.Rows(I).Cells(0).Font.Size = 12
 I = I + 1
```

Next

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Thank You

[image]

Edited with new info

```
        <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" datakeys="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-hover" Width="30%">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Text">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblText" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TestText") %>' Font-Size="14" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Font">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblFont" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Font") %>' Font-Size="14" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>

     If Not IsPostBack Then
     Dim DSFONTS As DataSet = GetDS("Select 'TestText' as TestText, fontname as font from fonts order by fontname")
     GridView1.DataSource = DSFONTS
     GridView1.DataBind()
 End If

 ' Grabfonts()
```

End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

```
     Dim lblFont As Label = e.Row.FindControl("lblFont")
     Dim lblText As Label = e.Row.FindControl("lblText")

     lblText.Style.Add("font-family", $"'{lblFont.Text}'")

 End If
```

End Sub

The only thing I changed from your code was the font size.  I verified my Dataset was populated correctly.  Can't seem to find out what I'm missing

Comment: If this is a Web Forms app then it should be tagged as such. That would make it obvious that it's a `GridView` and not a `DataGridView`. If you're talking about a third-party WinForms control then you should tell us who the author is and provide a link to the appropriate site. Also, it's a `GridView`, not a "GRIDVIEW". Use the actual name and wrap type and member names in graves (the "backtick" on the tilde key).

Comment: @ jmcilhinney   The Title stated Gridview. My Opening words in my message were "Using a "GRIDVIEW" . That should have made it blatantly obvious enough to anyone.   I put it in capital letters to emphasize it was indeed a GridView. Excuse me for trying to emphasize and make a point which was obviously missed.   But just to make sure I added a sentence starting with "I have the gridview (not a datagridview) ".  And it is a webforms app. Excuse my unforgivable massive blunder of not mentioning it.   I see you have a 52k reputation. Is this how you get points by sniping and criticizing posts.

Comment: How would sniping and criticising get me rep points? That makes no sense and is clearly just to make you feel better. When people do the wrong thing I tell them, so they can stop doing it. If you would rather not be criticised, don't do anything wrong. Alternatively, accept the criticism and do the right thing in future, as I did when I started here. You seem to be reacting as though criticism of what you do is an attack on who you are. It's not, so you should get over that.

Comment: There, I've added the missing tags for you. Took far less time than it did for you to write your comment justifying not doing it.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, for formatting rows of a Grid view, the preferred event is to the use the row data bind event. So, say setting color of a control, row calculations, or whatever? The row data binding event is rather nice, since it ALSO can enjoy use of all of the columns from the data source, and even columns that are NOT in the GridView markup can be freely used. So, you can have some column that say sets the color of the given row, but you don't have to show nor include that column in the GridView markup.

So, assuming this table of data:

| ID | TestText | Font |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TEST TEXT | Arial Black |
| 2 | TEST TEXT | Calibri |
| 3 | TEST TEXT | Courier New |
| 4 | TEST TEXT | Free 3 of 9 |
| 5 | TEST TEXT | Gigi |
| 6 | TEST TEXT | Informal Roman |
| 7 | TEST TEXT | OCR A Extended |
| 8 | TEST TEXT | Arial |

So, our GridView markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
    datakeys="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    CssClass="table table-hover"  Width="30%">

    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Text">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblText" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("TestText") %>'
                    Font-Size="16" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Font">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblFont" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("Font") %>'
                    Font-Size="16" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

And the code behind to load the GridView is this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        Dim strSQL =
            "SELECT * FROM tblFontFun
             ORDER BY ID"
        GridView1.DataSource = MyRst(strSQL)
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        Dim lblFont As Label = e.Row.FindControl("lblFont")
        Dim lblText As Label = e.Row.FindControl("lblText")

        lblText.Style.Add("font-family", $"'{lblFont.Text}'")

    End If

End Sub
```

And the result is this:

[image]

## Edit: The fonts will have to be loaded.

Of course the other issue is that such fonts may well NOT be installed and available on the client computer. As a result, you need to ensure that such fonts are loaded.

Say I hunt around and find a "calculator" font.

So, I can now add say to my fonts folder the following font:

[image]

Ok, so now on that page, I need to include that font.

Hence, I have this:

```
    <title></title>

    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.6.4.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>


    <style type="text/css">
     @font-face
     {
          font-family: 'myCalculator';
          src: url('/fonts/Calculator.ttf');
     }
</style>
```

So, now in the markup, I can have this:

```
            <asp:Label ID="lblTime" runat="server" Text="123456789" 
            style="font-size:32px;font-family:myCalculator;
                font-weight:bold;color:red;
                border-style:solid;
                border-color:black;padding:4px"        
               >
            </asp:Label>
```

And the result is now this:

[image]

Comment: Thank  You Albert. I really do appreciate you answer.  I've updated my original post to show what I'm seeing here. The fonts are not changing. I deleted my code and put yours in its place. Not getting the fonts to change still.

Comment: You using templated columns. So, for default (auto generated) columns, you use the .cells() collection. However, for templated columns, you have to use FindControl to get the controls, and cells() collection is of little use. So, for templated columns, you have to use .FindControl to get the controls.  So, keep in mind the rule: default autogenerated columns = use cells() collection. For templated controls/columns, you use .FindControl.

Comment: Ah, I see you ARE using find control now. So, see my edit. You have to ensure that the fonts are available and loaded. In my case, I assumed the fonts were installed client side, and that's not really a practical approach here. So, see my edit, I show how the fonts can be added to your web site.

Comment: Hi Albert, I will have over 150+ fonts eventually. Will I have to add each one individually to the .css file  I'll be working back on that project tomorrow hopefully.  Thank You again

Comment: Yes, but you make a global css file for that.  And if using a master page, then you only have to include it one time.  I mean, we all often use fontawsone, or the bootstrap gylphicons this way. I not sure I would adopt 150 fonts, but you can. Do a proof of concept, and say test 2-3 to make sure it works, and then you can go all out and add them all. That does seem like a LOT of fonts to want here, but if you need them, then so be it.

Comment: Hi Albert,  My Niece is a graphics designer and she has downloaded/purchased all these fonts. She want a webpage where she can enter a few words and then see the words in all her fonts.  I tried steering her to google fonts but....

Comment: No worries- sounds kind of cool...